# Import Android pickphotos

Tags: android, gradle, android-library, gradle-dependencies

We are trying to import the android-pickphotos project (https://github.com/crosswall/Android-PickPhotos) in order to use the photos picker but we are getting some troubles. We haven't found the gradle module anywhere and, when trying to import the module from a directory we face the following error:

```
Error:(29, 0) Cannot get property 'appcompat' on extra properties extension as it does not exist.
```

How can we do in order to import and use that library? Is there any other similar library that can be imported through the gradle's module and that allows some color customizations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: got the same problem - did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we do in order to import and use that library?

Clone the repository and add it as a module dependency, or copy the library package into your project.

> Is there any other similar library that can be imported through the
>   gradle's module and that allows some color customizations?

There is no mention of the dependency to add in the `Readme.md` in the repository. The author is not destributing it via `jcenter()` or `mavencentral()`. Only when distributed through these or another such distribution channel, the libray can be added as a dependency to the project's `build.gradle`.